# if else statement within a function ...which is a good practice?

Tags: c

I have 2 piece of code that I would like to know the reason for using either one.Both works but which is a good practice in C?

Option 1

```
Void GoodPractice()
{
  bool flag;

  if (right)
  {
    flag=1;
  }
  else
  {
    flag=0;
  }
}
```

OR

Option 2

```
Void GoodPractice()
{
  bool flag=0;

  if (right)
  {
    flag=1;
  }
}
```

Let me know why as well.
Thanks.

Comment: umm... these don't do anthing, maybe your real question is if this flag is returned from function?

Comment: in this case is just a readability matter

Comment: `flag` and `right` seem to be the same thing.

Comment: with initializaton,option two looks much more cleaner way to it..

Comment: Surely if this is a real world example then you could just cast the right variable as an integer and retrieve the correct number without any funny business?

    flag = int(right);

If we really are going on simplicity/shortness?

Comment: @shennan No need for a cast:  flag = right != 0;

Comment: @CareyGregory Apologies, I figured that right was a bool and flag was supposed to be an int. It is, indeed, the other way round.

Comment: `#define GoodPractice(x) (x) ? True : False`, use it: `bool flag = GoodPractice(right);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do.

In general second version  is better than the first one, because there is no code section where flag is not defined.

```
Void GoodPractice()
{
   bool flag=0;
   // you can use flag  
   if (right)
   {
      flag=1;
   }
}

Void NotAsGoodPractice()
{
   bool flag;
   // you can't use flag, because it has no defined value
   if (right)
   {
      flag=1;
   }
   else
       flag=0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither...

```
void GoodPractice()
{
  bool flag = right;

  // though I would return it  ;)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool flag = right != 0; // if you want to be more explicit
```

Comment: The second example will work, but not necessarily the first.  In C, `right` can be something other than a `bool`, but still work in a comparison.

Comment: He used right in if condition so it is convertable to bool

Comment: The second solution is the only safe, portable one.  I would +1 if you had omitted the first rather bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these code examples are functionally equivalent, so the real difference is a mater of style.

However, there could be a case where one is clearer than the other.

For example in a short function the second option is clear but the second option would be less clear if there is a lot of code between the `bool flag=0` and the if statement.

I've used both exactly for these type of reasons.  Look at the code, which seems clearer to you.

Answer (score -1):

In my humble opinion , i feel this is better.

```
Void GoodPractice()
 {
 bool flag;

  if (right)
  {
    flag=1;
  }
  else
  {
    flag=0;
  }
}
```

Yes it increases the number of lines of codes , and may take an extra CPU cycle or two.

But i feel , there can be less chances of making an error , by writing code in a clear way , that covers all possible logic types.

Comment: Why is the second example unclear?

Comment: @RobertHarvey

It is clear in this scenario , but may not be if there is several lines of code separating declaration of flag , and  conditional testing of flag , because you may forget to initialize flag to zero , or some code in between may change the value of flag.
    Happened once or twice with me.

Comment: Ah, you're one of those "always use braces, even when there's only one line of code" guys. :)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how 8 lines of code are more clear than the single line `flag = right != 0;`.